# Why am I receiving null values for these input elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mongodb, meteor

I am working on a meteor based application and make updates to my DB based off form inputs. When i look up the data in my mongodb the fields are valued as null which isnt the case since i can see their values posted in the url as well i am  the one inputting them. Here is the code i have currently implemented.

```
<template name="room">
   <div class="container">
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <h1>{{currentUser.username}} Cards</h1>
      <hr>
      <h2>Fill out the form below to add a card</h2>
      <form class="new-card">
         <input type="text" name="notes" placeholder="Enter some notes on the sprint" />
         <input id="good-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="category" value="Good">Good
         <input id="bad-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="category" value="Bad">Bad
         <!-- <button class="new-card" type="submit">Add Card</button>-->
      </form>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
         {{#each cards}}
         {{> card}}
         {{/each}}
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <h1>Revealed Cards</h1>
      <hr>
   </div>
</template>
```

Meteor.js:

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'main-layout'
});
Router.route('/', {
    name: 'home',
    template: 'login'
});
cards = new Mongo.Collection("cards");
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Router.route('/room', {
        name: 'room',
        template: 'room'
    });
    if (!Meteor.user()) {
        if (Meteor.loggingIn()) { /*we dont want to do anything*/ } else {
            alert("Sorry, you must be logged in first to use our services.");
            Router.go('/');
        }
    }
    Template.room.helpers({
        cards: function() {
            //return all cards in db sort by newest
            return cards.find({}, {
                sort: {
                    createdAt: -1
                }
            });
        }
    });
    Template.body.events({
        "submit .new-card": function(event) {
            //prevent the browsers default behavior for this event
            event.preventDefault();
            var notes = event.target.text.value;
            var good = $('#good-checkbox:checked').val();
            var bad = $('#bad-checkbox:checked').val();
            if (!good && !bad || !notes || notes.length === 0) {
                alert("No fields can be left blank");
            } else {
                cards.insert({
                    notes: notes,
                    good: good,
                    bad: bad,
                    createdAt: new Date(),
                    createdBy: Meteor.user().username
                });
            }
            event.target.text.value = "";
        }
    });
    Template.room.events({
        "click #addCard": function() {
            alert("inserted card");
            cards.insert({
                text: null,
                category: null,
                createAt: new Date(),
                createdBy: Meteor.user().username
            });
        }
    });
    Accounts.ui.config({
        passwordSignupFields: "USERNAME_ONLY"
    });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function() {
        // code to run on server at startup
    });
}
```

Comment: Try using `event.target.value` instead of `event.target.text.value` for `notes`. Are there any console errors?

Comment: I found the fix. I needed to name it Template.room.helpers not template.body.helpers also since the event is triggered via the button click and submit it was better for me to use jquery than using the event param.

Answer (score 0):

As [Shaunak D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3639582/shaunak-d) already pointed out in the comments, the `notes` variable in your `submit .new-card` event handler is `undefined`. Use `event.target.notes.value` instead of `event.target.text.value`.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.room.helpers({
        cards: function() {
            //return all cards in db sort by newest
            return cards.find({}, {
                sort: {
                    createdAt: -1
                }
            });
        }
    });
    Template.room.events({
        "submit .new-card": function(event) {
            //prevent the browsers default behavior for this event
            event.preventDefault();
            var notes = event.target.notes.value;
            var good = $('#good-checkbox:checked').val();
            var bad = $('#bad-checkbox:checked').val();
            if (!good && !bad || !notes || notes.length === 0) {
                alert("No fields can be left blank");
            } else {
                cards.insert({
                    notes: notes,
                    good: good,
                    bad: bad,
                    createdAt: new Date(),
                    createdBy: Meteor.user().username
                });
            }
            event.target.notes.value = "";
        }
    });
}
```

Here's a [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/HQ3n77FjeAwou7ZX5/Null-Values-Cards).